# Xcode 4.2 Reset Default Layout

Tags: xcode, layout, window, xcode4.2

I don't know what I did but my view is totally screwed up to the max.  It only shows one window at a time now (For example: editor only) and no matter what settings I change on the "view" panel at the top, nothing seems to help.  Is there a way to restore Xcode 4.2 to its default layout?

Comment: Try quitting Xcode, trashing Xcode's preferences file, and restarting Xcode. Trashing the preferences file should restore the default layout. The preferences file is in ~/Library/Preferences and is named com.apple.Xcode.plist

Comment: I tried that, Xcode boots up like normal and has me accept the terms as if it were freshly re-booted, but then it crashes every time.  :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to manually enable all toolbars in the "view" tab.

Comment: It's brutal but it's true. Doesn't have the ease-of-use Apple usually touts.

Comment: How come they haven't got a "Reset views" option? This is ridiculous!

Comment: If I ever get a job working for Apple, I'll be sure to ask them for you!

Answer (score 5):

Same as MrHappy says...

#### Step 1:

[Screen Shot 2013-08-01 at 10.50.02 PM.png http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/2723/kh3p.png](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/2723/kh3p.png)

#### Step 2:

Click all of the view buttons in the top right of the toolbar:

[oeqm.png http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/6383/rdth.png](http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/6383/rdth.png)

Done.